# Clojure Heroku Worker Dyno Queue

Tags: clojure, heroku, queue, backend, worker

Is it possible to have a job queue for a Clojure webapp on Heroku? I see that you can do delayed jobs and use celery for Rails and Django, is there anything similar for Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IronMQ is available on Heroku, and there's a Clojure library that allows you to work with it:

https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_clojure

(I notice that there is a problem/feature where if you pass something other than a string as a message to the Iron MQ clojure library, it'll save an empty string.  The easy work-around is to serialize everything as clojure reader forms.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the specifics of job queue management in Clojure, but if you can start the process from the command line you can run it on Heroku:

http://neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend/